# Syntax error on prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error, prepared-statement

I have this query

```
$q1 = "UPDATE klanten SET (
       kla_tel2,
       kla_mobiel,
       kla_fax,
       kla_btw_nummer,
       kla_bankrekening,
       kla_ww,
       kla_bez_straat,
       kla_bez_nummer,
       kla_bez_toev,
       kla_bez_pc,
       kla_bez_plaats,
       kla_bez_land_id,
       kla_post_straat,
       kla_post_nummer,
       kla_post_toev,
       kla_post_postbus,
       kla_post_pc,
       kla_post_plaats,
       kla_post_land_id,
       kla_fac_straat,
       kla_fac_nummer,
       kla_fac_toev,
       kla_fac_postbus
       kla_fac_pc,
       kla_fac_plaats,
       kla_fac_land_id,
       kla_sidn_owner,
       kla_reg_status,
       kla_rechtspersoon
       )
       VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
       WHERE kla_id=" . $kla_id;
```

But when executed it gives me a syntax error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( kla_tel2, kla_mobiel, kla_fax, kla_btw_num' at line 1: SQL: UPDATE klanten SET ...`

What I know is that all values are filled and that `$kla_id` is filled too, but as this is a SQL Syntax error that shouldn't be a problem.

**EDIT**

MySql Client Version is 5.0.51a
Server Version is 5.0.51a-24+lenny4
Protocol version is 10

Comment: That is not valid syntax. It`s `UPDATE table SET col1=val1,col2=val2...`

Comment: show the [mySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/update.html) how an `update statement` loks like.

Comment: `$q1 = "UPDATE klanten SET kla_tel2=?, kla_mobiel=? ... WHERE kla_id=" . $kla_id;` that's the update syntax

Comment: In another script I use `INSERT INTO klanten (kla_naam, kla_tel1, kla_email, kla_reg_status) VALUES (?,?,?,?)` and it works fine

Comment: Your syntax is the problem

Comment: Insert and update are different syntax wise.

Comment: @mihai ah I see, thanks. so if I make it `UPDATE klanten SET kla_tel2=?, kla_fax=?...` I should be fine?

Comment: Yes,that would work,at least the syntax is fine.

Comment: "In another script I use INSERT INTO klanten (kla_naam, kla_tel1,` ..." so? one is an `INSERT` which is different to an `UPDATE` in an insert there is no existing data; for an update there is existing data; conditions are different so there is different syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong `UPDATE` syntax. Please see [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) for more info.

The right syntax looks like:

```
UPDATE klanten SET kla_tel2 = <some_value>, kla_mobiel = <some_other_value> WHERE kla_id = <some_third_value>
```

You can also use this with prepared SQL statements like your example above, using question marks.